# Do I have to use T-Student to calculate this confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, poisson-distribution, confidence-interval

Given a distribution $X~Pois(λ)$ with unknown parameter $λ=E(X)$ with $14$ random observations given from this distribution.
How do I calculate a confidence Interval at $95\%$ for $λ?$ Do I have to use T-Student or normal distribution? (I personally think I have to use T-Student, since $λ$ is unknown and n is small).

I tried it in the following way:
$λ =$ Mean([14 Values]) = 8
$pt(0.975, 13) = 0.8263$
Confidence interval: $(λ - 0.8263\sqrt{(λ/n)}, λ + 0.8263\sqrt{(λ/n)})$

Is my approach correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Student t distribution is used when you are estimating the mean of a Normal model with unknown variance. Here the model is not normal. It's a poisson one.

$n=14$ is great enough to use a Gaussian approximation for the interval.

Using CLT we know that, with $n$ great enough, $\overline{X}_n\dot{\sim} N(\lambda;\frac{\lambda}{n})$ thus the pivotal quantity is the following

$$\frac{\overline{X}_n-\lambda}{\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{n}}}$$

**First approximation**

Estimate standard deviation with $\sqrt{\frac{\overline{X}_n}{n}}$

Then solving in $\lambda$

$$-1.96\leq \frac{8-\lambda}{\sqrt{\frac{8}{14}}}\leq 1.96$$

That is

$$\lambda \in[6.52;9.48]$$

**Second approximation**

Solve in $\lambda$ the following double inequality

$$-1.96\leq \frac{8-\lambda}{\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{14}}}\leq 1.96$$

getting, after some algebraic calculations

$$8+\frac{1.96^2}{28}\pm\sqrt{\Bigg(\frac{1.96^2}{28}\Bigg)^2+8\frac{1.96^2}{14}}$$

That is

$$\lambda\in[6.65;9.63]$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Is there another way to calculate the confidence interval in this case?
Since we haven't learned about the Gaussian approximation I'm not sure if this is the "way" we should solve this exercise.

Comment: @Peter : Gaussian approximation is the Central Limit Theorem... Did you study it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confused. Yes, we studied the Central Limit Theorem.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Peter:  I did some edits in my answer explaining the same solution with different words. I hope now it is clear

Comment: Thank you for the edit :)
But we haven't studied the approximation with two steps. What does the "second approximation" step do?

Comment: @Peter : use the first I showed. It's correct. The second is just a more accurate one